# Pass Unicode characters from nodejs to C++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js

I use this code to get `char *`:

```
String::Utf8Value name(args[0]);
```

But how to get `wchar_t *`? I need to pass Unicode characters like 'ტესტ'.

Comment: `wchar_t` would be for utf16, but it seems you want utf-8.

Comment: You know that UTF-8 is *byte* encoded Unicode? Which makes `char` (and `char*`) a perfect match for it.

Comment: @Jarod42 `wchar_t` is not always for UTF-16: on Linux e.g. `sizeof(wchar_t)==4`, which makes it more fit for UTF-32.

Comment: @Ruslan: `sizeof(wchar_t)` can even be `1`, so should not be used at all for encoding, but `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint16_t`, `std::uint32_t` are valid options for utf-8, utf-16, utf-32 respectively.

Comment: Your strange characters are still utf8.

Comment: @Jarod42 it's funny that `char16_t` doesn't appear to be a good candidate for encoding of UTF-16 strings: it has the same size as `uint_least16_t`, which can be wider than 16 bits.